# Django Filtering performance if using [:max]

Tags: python, django

Assume I have a table with 100000 entries but I am doing that :

```
a = model.object.all()[:10]
```

Will the SQL limit the request to 10 or Django will generate an SQL to get all table and provide me with 10 entries?

That's probably a Python question more than Django, but I want to make sure I am not doing something wrong.

Comment: Django's ORM supports SQL logging: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django will use SQL LIMIT.

- [Limiting QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets)

---

```
class M(models.Model):
    pass

... 

print M.objects.all()[:10].query
# SELECT "app_m"."id" FROM "app_m" LIMIT 10
```